# az bot publish error: Not a valid azure publish directory. missing post deploy scripts

Tags: node.js, botframework, publish, azure-cli

I am trying to deploy my chatbot code created using ms bot framework node.js sdk version 3. I am using az cli to login, create and publish the bot in that order. But it fails in the bot publishing step. The publish command is as below:

```
az bot publish -n TestBot1333 -g MYRESOURCEGROUP --code-dir 1546598242066_chatbot
```

The error is as below:

```
ERROR: Not a valid azure publish directory. missing post deploy scripts
```

Looks like it is expecting C# code instead of Node.js. Could anyone please let me know how to publish Node.js code to webapp bot.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a postDeployScripts folder? If so, try running the `az bot publish...` command from the root folder of the bot and using `--code-dir "."`

Comment: No I do not have post deploy scripts in that folder.

Comment: Do you follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript)? And the error shows the directory is valid. Maybe you can try "In .env, update the botFilePath property to point to the new .bot file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying Node can be much more difficult than it should be, especially due to the lack of V3 docs. I've submitted pull requests for doc changes to make it easier. In the meantime, I have some steps you can try (that I have tested on a variety of V3 and V4 bots and creation methods):

*Note: These steps should also work for V4. Just change `v3` to `v4` as applicable. Generally speaking, these steps follow [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript)*

**If you haven't created a Web Bot App Resource in Azure, go to the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)**:

1. Add an app - Name becomes `<bot-resource-name>`
2. Create New
3. Don't check Guided
4. Copy App Id
5. Generate Password and Copy it

**If you haven't already, create the remaining Azure Resources. From root of bot's folder:**

```
az login
az bot create --kind webapp --name <bot-resource-name> --location <geographic-location> --version v3 --lang <language> --verbose --resource-group <resource-group-name> --appid "<application-id>" --password "<application-password>"
```

**Create a .bot file for your project (if it's missing)**

In the root folder of your project, run:

```
msbot init
```

**Encrypt your local bot, if necessary. From root of bot's folder:**

```
msbot secret --new
```

Copy the generated secret and paste it in your .env file

**Add your newly-created production endpoint to your local bot. From root of bot's folder:**

```
msbot connect endpoint --endpoint "https://<your-endpoint>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages" --name production --appId "<application-id>" --appPassword "<application-password>" --secret "<bot-file-secret>"
```

**Open .bot file in Bot Emulator and add remaining services (LUIS, storage, etc), as necessary:**

1. Open the bot in the Bot Framework Emulator
2. In the Bot Explorer pane (on the left), click the `+` next to Services
3. Enter the appropriate information and repeat for each service used

**If you're using v3, you may need to prepare the bot for publication. From the root of your bot's folder:**

```
az bot prepare-publish --name <bot-resource-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --proj-name "" --sln-name ""
```

*Note: If you're publishing a C# bot, you'll need to fill out `--proj-name` and `--sln-name` as applicable. If you're deploying in node, you still have to include it (for now), but just use blank argument parameters like in the example above.*

**Publish the bot to Azure. From root of bot's folder:**

```
az bot publish --name <bot-resource-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --code-dir "." --verbose --version v3
```

*Note: It may timeout while "emptying /site/wwwroot" folder. Just run the command again until it goes through*

*Note: It may present a 500 error while "installing node dependencies". Ignore this because it still works.*

*Note: You may also need to go into the App Service and make sure it has the right `botFileSecret` and `botFilePath` environment variables*

Comment: do you have npm module for `az bot` like `luis-apis`. I am trying to deploy the bot using node.js script. Also, do I need to have .bot file for the bot ?

Comment: I am getting error that when running the prep-publish command:
az bot prepare-publish --name TestB1547471131847 --resource-group MyResource --proj-name "" --sln-name ""

ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\demo\\TestB1547471131847\\deploy.cmd'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: The publish command also fails saying:
ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: --version v3

Comment: 1) the `az bot` command comes from the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).  2) Since you're on V4, you likely don't need the `prepare-publish` command. Before publishing, though, you'll probably have to build the bot first with `npm build`. 3) `--version` is supported in the azure CLI. Download the latest version from the link in #1 of this comment.

Comment: the bot gets published if we have PostDeployScripts folder in the root directory. But it doesn't seem to have installed all the npm modules. It installed the modules under node_modules/.staging folder. Could you please let where can I find valid PostDeployScripts folder ?

Comment: PostDeployScripts isn't always necessary. What bot template did you start from/how did you originally create the bot? After downloading the bot, did you run `npm install` from the root folder? That should be all you need to do to install all of the node modules. And for clarification, is your bot publishing to Azure, or not?

Comment: No, I didn't execute npm install from the root folder before publishing. I thought that its part of publish command. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I am using Azure web app bot. Also why do I need .bot file ? I think create and publish are enough for me.

Comment: The bot is getting deployed but it throws the following error:
Error: Refresh access token failed with status code: 400
    at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:697:36)

Comment: is there a command to auto generate AppId and AppPassword while creating the bot?

Comment: Running `npm install` needs to be run on your local machine while developing (it may run automatically, depending on how you download the bot). It does automatically run on the Azure server after publishing. For the "Refresh access token" error, you can try 1) Restarting the App Service in Azure that the bot uses. 2) Follow steps in the auth troubleshooting doc. If none of that works, I'll need to know exactly what steps you used to create and deploy the bot so that I can try to reproduce it.

I don't believe there's a command that auto-generates AppId and AppPassword during creation.

Comment: And `.bot` file isn't needed for V3 bots. I just find it easier to manage endpoints and use with the Emulator.

Comment: I already have the necessary code for the bot to run locally. I just want to create the bot and upload all the files from my local folder to the bot created. How can I achieve that ? The publish command doesn't seem to upload all the node modules.

Comment: If you're still getting the "Refresh access token failed" error. that often means that your `appId` or `appPassword` are incorrect. If they are, indeed, correct, you can try [these troubleshooting steps](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/troubleshooting-bot-framework-authentication/). I've also found that when having trouble deploying, it can help to delete all of my Azure resources and restart the deployment process from scratch, being sure to follow every step exactly as written above or in the docs.

Comment: what about the node_modules which are installed partially ?

Comment: Looks like I was still using the older version of Azure CLI. Installed the latest from the link above and node_modules were uploaded correctly. Deployment works fine, but still cant get rid of:
Error: Refresh access token failed with status code: 400
Is there a problem with below credentials:
ae192129-1349-4183-8d98-08db54bb0584,
%V;/GnVtH]vD5/j?
I am so close. Could you please help.

Comment: I'm glad your deployment succeeded! I can't tell from that Id/password combo whether or not anything is wrong, but looking at the server logs, I can see that the appId indeed points to your bot, `TestBot1547816838`. [Go here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) and verify that your `appId` and `appPassword` matches. If it doesn't, just click "Generate New Password" and then copy that new password into your deployed bot.

Comment: You can also try [going here](https://TestBot1547816838.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/:vs.output), restart the server by clicking Run, and watch the output while attempting to message your bot. By the way, you should edit your last comment and remove your password :).

Comment: I did not register my application before starting to deploy the bot. I think its mandatory to register the application and retrieve appId and password. There s an error which I get while running the publish command.
Detected language javascript. Installing node dependencies in remote bot.
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
Traceback (most recent call last):

But the deployment seems to be complete. How to get past this last one error ?

Comment: Also, does the publish command execute the npm install command on its own on the server.

Comment: There's some issues when deploying with Node, currently. If you get the `RemoteDisconnected` error, just try publishing again until it gets to `installing node dependencies`, which is when--yes--it runs the `npm install` command on the server. Once it makes it to this step, it tends to send an error, even though it actually worked.

Comment: I am still facing issues when deploying with Node. Is this issue going to be fixed in the near future ? It would be great if it works. Also the delete bot command does not delete associated resources with the bot. How do we delete the bot and associated resources as well.

Comment: It depends on what issue you're referring to. As far as I know, all of them are fixed. I recall seeing a bug fix request for the timeout after `installing node dependencies`, but I believe it got fixed and closed (can't seem to find it again).

`az bot delete` should only delete the bot app service, not all of them. To delete them all, `az group delete -g <resourceGroupName> --no-wait`, but that will delete your whole Resource Group.

Comment: I am referring to the publish command issue. All the other commands work fine.

Comment: What publish issues are you still having (other than the timeout after `installing node dependencies`)?

Comment: Yes, the same mentioned above. Remote disconnected.

Comment: If it's coming after the `installing node dependencies` step, everything actually worked just fine and it threw an error anyway (this should have been fixed in recent releases, too). If it's coming before, the error is so infrequent, I don't know if/when it will be fixed. I think it's more of an Azure thing.

Comment: I have .env file in my code directory. After running the publish command .env file is not uploaded to wwwroot. How do I use .env file instead of variables from application settings ?

Comment: .env file doesn't upload, for security purposes. Instead, the bot will look for the ENV settings in Azure Portal > {Your Web App Bot} > Application Settings.

[Here's an image](https://imgur.com/X7zAnzH)

Comment: As your bot seems to have published, do you mind marking this as answered so I can close the support ticket on my end? Thanks!

Comment: yes, I will do that. Is there a way to update the Application settings using az cli ?

Comment: Sure can!

`az webapp config appsettings set -g <ResourceGroup> -n <ResourceName> --subscription <AZsubscription> --settings SettingToChange=SettingValue`